# Convert LaTeX book to presentation and handouts

Tags: presentations, books

I have written a LateX "book", with `section`, `figure` and my custom defined `example`.

Somehow, I would like to convert this into:

1. A presentation PDF
2. A handout PDF

I've been experimenting with Beamer, and this seems to get the job done but I don't want to have to manually extract out all the content - it becomes a pain if I want to change something.

**Is there a way to markup the presentation content in the article?**

The key aspect of this question is that: in my book I define a series of `examples`; in the presentation, I would like to reference a subset of them but in doing so, ensuring that the numbering is the same in the presentation as the book.

Comment: You could use `beamer` from the get-go—http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beamerarticle

Answer (score 1):

A book/article and the corresponding slides are *wildly* different documents. A book contains detailed discussion, examples, exercises. Slides are mostly bullet points and some details. Where a book can be a few hundred pages, there will be many fewer slides, with even less text on them. There just is no way to "convert" a book (or article for that matter) into slides.

In `beamer` you can write a single source that gets processed into an article or book, or into slides. It requires careful layout to do so, see the examples in the documentation. This should be useful to keep the article and the slides for a conference synchronized, but I've never tried to do that.